# setLookAtM parameters in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es

In setLookAtM(matrix, 0, eyex, eyey, eyez, lookx, looky, lookz, upx, upy, upz), clearly the eye parameters specify a position vector eye. But what about the look and up vectors. Are these direction vectors or are they position vectors?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eye and Look vectors are positional and the Up vector is directional only.